# Unknown number of payments

Tags: finance, actuarial-science

A fund of 3000\$ is to be accumulated by n annual payments of 65\$ at the end of each year, followed by n annual payments of 135\$ at the end of each year, plus a smaller final payment made one year after the last regular payment. If the effective rate of interest is 6% per year, find n and the amount of the final irregular payment

Can someone help me with this problem, I started something but I need help to solve the rest .. 
What I did from now is that 3000 = (65x S[n,6%] ) + (135x S[n,6%]) + X
Where the x is the final irregular payment
thank you

Comment: Regardless of wether your equation is 100% correct (but almost in my view), it can be seen that you have one equation and two variables ($n,X$). That means that a specific value for $X$ and $n$ each can not be determined.

Answer (score 0):

In my view we have $n$ payments of $p=65\$$ and then other $n$ payments of $q=135\$$ and a last payment $x$. Let be $i=6\%$, $S=3,000\$$ and $n=\lfloor N\rfloor$ the number of year (integer).

The last payment $x$ will be made $1$ year after $n$ payments $p$ and after other $n$ payments $q$, i.d. at year $2n+1$.The first payment $p$ will produce the value $p s_{\overline{n}|i}$ at year $n$ and this amount will produce the sum $p s_{\overline{n}|i}(1+i)^{n+1}$ after other $n+1$ years, i.e. at year $2n+1$. Analogously for the stream $q$ we have $q s_{\overline{n}|i}$ after $n$ years and this amount will produce the sum $q s_{\overline{n}|i}(1+i)$ after another $1$ year.

The equation for $S$ is
$$
S=p s_{\overline{n}|i}(1+i)^{n+1}+q(1+i)s_{\overline{n}|i}+x\tag 1
$$

Without the last payment $x$ and for a not integer number of years $N$ we would have after $2N+1$ years the sum
$$
S=p s_{\overline{N}|i}(1+i)^{N+1}+q(1+i)s_{\overline{N}|i}=p\,\frac{y-1}{i}y\,(1+i)+q\,y\,\frac{y-1}{i}\tag 2
$$
where $y=(1+i)^N>0$. The equation (2) becomes
$$
y(y-1)=\frac{iS}{p(1+i)+q}\tag 3
$$
So we have that the positive root of eq. (3) is
$ y^+\approx 1.564$ and then
$$
N=\frac{\log(y^+)}{\log(1+i)}\approx7.8
$$
So we have $$n=\lfloor N\rfloor=7$$ and from eq. (1) we find 
$$
x\approx 426.53\$
$$

Answer (score 0):

Your final value equation should be

$3000 = [ 65 * S(2n,6\%) + 70 * S(n,6\%) ] (1.06) + X$

Note the known payments stop 1 year before the final payment, so there's another year's interest. And it's easier to think of it as a payment of $65$ running for $2n$ years and an *additional* payment of $70$ running for $n$ years.

Now solve for $n$ in

$3000 = [ 65 * S(2n,6\%) + 70 * S(n,6\%) ] (1.06)$

and round down, since we require $n$ an integer. Substitute that $n$ back into

$X = 3000 - [ 65 * S(2n,6\%) + 70 * S(n,6\%) ] (1.06)$

to get the irregular payment.